# How to add proxy with username and password to Jsoup?

Tags: java, proxy, jsoup

I am working on a Java application that need to connect to internet though proxy (with username and password). But it does not work. Could someone help me fix this? My java code below:

```
    final String authUser = "username";
    final String authPassword = "password";

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
        }
    });

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.123.12.123");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1234");

    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup 
                .connect("https://www.google.com").timeout(60000)
                .header("Content-Language", "en-US")
                .get();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can  you explain what doesn't work?  What do you expect? What is it doing instead?  Are you seeing an error?

Comment: I added error log. Could you have a look for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "username");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "password");
```

or

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "username");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2180)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:169)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:142)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:732)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:707)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:297)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:286)
at com.html.proxy.MyProxySelector.connectProxy(MyProxySelector.java:46)
at com.html.proxy.MyProxySelector.main(MyProxySelector.java:56)
```

I want to access to a webpage (for example gooogle.com) though proxy (for example: "192.123.12.123:123" and use username,password)